# Deploying Gmail Apis Project Authentification probleme

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail-api

when i use the app in local (on executing with visual studio) there is no probleme, but when i deploy my project the authentification doesn't work.
the probleme is situated here :

```
    string path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    FileDataStore file = new FileDataStore(path);

    credential =new GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker().AuthorizeAsync(
                            new ClientSecrets
                            {
                                ClientId = "Client_ID",
                                ClientSecret = "Client_Secret"
                            },
                            Scopes,
                            "me",
                            CancellationToken.None
                            , file
                            ).Result;
```

Comment: Could you share what is the error message or the error code?

Comment: the error is here :  private bool OpenBrowser(string url)
        {
     
            Process.Start(url);
            return true;
        } it tell me access denied

Comment: i found the error after placing all error log in a text file, from the Google.Apis.Auth project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution (one of X) by my self so let begin:

First we generate the authorization url manually, look:

```
Response.Redirect("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?"+
                "redirect_uri="+ WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUrl"].ToString() + "&" +
                "prompt=consent&"+
                "response_type=code&"+
                "client_id=" + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientID"].ToString() + "&" +
                "scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify&"+
                "access_type=offline"
                );
```

after that the RedirectUrl which I put on web config will be start after authentication and get a Code as parameter in the link (url with parameter Code), so now you just need to get token access, so lets see this code:

```
 protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                if (Request["code"] != null && Session["credential"] ==null)
                {
                    var result = await getTokenResponse(Request["code"].ToString()); // here we get the code posted by google

                }

            }
private static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly, GmailService.Scope.GmailModify };
        async Task<TokenResponse> getTokenResponse(String Code)
        {
            Code = Code.Replace("#", "");
            string redirectUri = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUrl"].ToString();
            var init2 = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer();
            ClientSecrets cli = new ClientSecrets(); 
            cli.ClientId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientID"].ToString(); // init the Client_ID
            cli.ClientSecret = "ClientSecret"; // init the Client_Secret
            init2.ClientSecrets = cli;
            init2.Scopes = Scopes;
            init2.DataStore = null; // you dont need to store token cause we w'll store it in Session object
            GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(init2); /// init the flow which w'll get the token object 
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken);
            var token = await flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync("me", Code, redirectUri, cancellationToken); 
            Response.Write(token);

            UserCredential credential = new UserCredential(flow, "me", token); // and know we have the credential 
            Session["credential"] = credential;
            return token;
        }
```

note:

1. this solution is for multi-client application.
2. for all requests with google apis we have: just a text or Json text returned by handlers.