# Grant access to Google API on hosting server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm developing a website that gets data from google calendar using google API,
So i grabbed the test code from google documentations and customized it. 
 
When I debugged it locally everything worked, it opened a new tab and asked for access to the google account like it should. 
 
This is the method I'm using for the response token i'm getting:

```
private static UserCredential GetCredential()
{
    UserCredential credential;
    var path = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "App_Data/credentials.json");
    using (var stream =
        new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        string credPath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, ".credentials/calendar-access.json");

        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
    }
    return credential;
}
```

My problem is on the server, when I'm trying get data from google for the first time the page goes to infinite loop. 
 
I'm afraid that the tab that suppose to get access from google account is opening on the server and that why it's going infinite loading. 
 
So my question is, 
first, if it's possible, and if it is, how can I fix it ? 
second, there is a better way to do so ?

Comment: All your files .json are in your server?

Comment: yes of course, I also noticed that the folders of the response token are created but without the token. that's why I suspect it's opening a tab in the server.

Comment: Did you check the implementation for [Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc)?

Comment: From what i'm getting this is for Authorizing google users login, I just need a to use my own google account for the calendar information.

Answer (score 1):

i have find one solution for this and make a multi-client authentification, look at my post here :

[Deploying Gmail Apis Project Authentification probleme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466654/deploying-gmail-apis-project-authentification-probleme)

Comment: I noticed that in my link there is a "destination" which I don't know, this solution isn't covering everything.

Comment: but it is, the credentials.json contain the Client_ID and Client_Secret and the calendar-access.json contain the token_access so you dont need to use the auth of google juste try my solution and tell me you repense

Comment: I don't have the token_access, that's what i'm trying to acquire, I only need it to work once so it will generate a response token and that will be saved on server.

Comment: with my solution you can get juste the Token var wich contain the token access or you can get the credential object to get service wich is needed to access to the mail, profil, .....

Comment: go read google api documentation and you w'll understand all :)

Comment: I have found a different solution but thank you for the lid.

Answer (score 0):

#### I have found a solution to I have wanted

I followed this [link](http://www.sparkhound.com/blog/google-oauth-integration-using-an-mvc-asp-net-app-1) 
This is exactly what i was searching for, it save the token in the memory and not creating a file, also generate URL and covers everything for the MVC